# Paypal subscription button. upgrade subscription amount

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am using paypal subscription button. if there is any method so that if user want to update his/her subscription amount after some time how could this achieve.
And how user can cancel his/her subscription ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a modify button to update the subscription.  If want to cancel the subscription, you as the merchatn can cancel this or the buyer can cancel this as well.  You can find more on using the modify and cancel features for subscriptions [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/#id08ADF500NXK).  If your subsriptions start with I- instead of S-, you can also use the [ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus_API_Operation_NVP/) to cancel the subscription as well.